# Why we should not use my when we want to shift?

Tags: perl

Why we should not use `my` for the variable  when we are using `shift` to initialize that??

example :

```
my $Value= shift @_ ;
```

why above statement was not accepted??

Comment: What do you mean by not accepted. Did you get a syntax error or was this rejected by a code review or what?

Comment: actually its showing a warning that shift @_ should not be used when your variable is declared as my . But when i declared variable as our it didn't show that warning.

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula: Please edit your question to add a small, complete runnable program that exhibits the problem, along with the **exact text** of the warning you are getting.

Comment: You need to tell us the exact warning. Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the exact warning into it. This sounds like a custom linter. Is this for school?

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula: Your question has been closed. But if you [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54781191/edit) to add the information we're asking for, then I'll be happy to vote to re-open it. All is not lost :-)

Answer (score 3):

What problems are you seeing? There's no reason for your code not to work.

I often write code like this:

```
my $self = shift;
```

The only effective difference from your code is that I don't explicitly give `shift()` an argument. Inside a subroutine, calling `shift()` without an argument will shift a value from `@_`. Outside of a subroutine, calling `shift()` without an argument will shift a value from `@ARGV`.

It's possible that you're using `@_` when you meant `@ARGV`, but without more context it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: actually its showing a warning that shift @_ should not be used when your variable is declared as my.

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula: You say "its showing". But **what** is producing that error? It doesn't sound like any of [Perl's standard diagnostic messages](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) (but, of course, it's hard to be sure from such a vague description).